# Repository doesn't have a find-one-method declared

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to reproduce code sample from https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#core.web.basic (Basic web support)

I have some controller in Spring Web MVC application:

```
@Controller    // This means that this class is a Controller
@RequestMapping(path = "/demo") // This means URL's start with /demo (after Application path)
@EnableSpringDataWebSupport
public class MainController {

    @GetMapping(path = "/getResById/{id}")
    @ResponseBody
    public Tresource getResById(@PathVariable("id") Tresource tr, Model m) {
        m.addAttribute(tr);
        return tr;
    }
}
```

The application main entry is the class with `@SpringBootApplication` annotation.

I also have repository class:

```
@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.READ_UNCOMMITTED)
public interface UserRepository extends Repository<Tresource, Long> {

//    List<Tresource> findByBrief(String brief);
    @Query("Select t.brief from Tresource t where t.resourceId=:resourceId")
    String qqq(@Param("resourceId") Long resourceId);

    Optional<Tresource> findDistinctByResourceIdOrBrief(Long resourceId, String brief);

    @Query("Select i from Tresource t "
            + "inner join Tinstitution i on i.institutionId=t.instOwnerId "
            + "where t.resourceId=:resourceId")
    Optional<Tinstitution> getResOwner(@Param("resourceId") Long resourceId);

}
```

This code gets exception

```
2018-03-21 14:33:15.977  WARN 11464 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Failed to bind request element: org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.mycompany.eurofatcafns.db.Tresource'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable com.mycompany.eurofatcafns.db.Tresource] for value '2010015161038'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Repository doesn't have a find-one-method declared!
```

when I am accessing /demo/getResById/2010015161038 .
What am I doing wrong with this code? How to fix this code?

Thank you very much!

Comment: you are passing 2010015161038 but in your controller you accept Treesource. How can this work? What is TreeSource class?

Comment: From the doc link: `As you can see the method receives a User instance directly and no further lookup is necessary. The instance can be resolved by letting Spring MVC convert the path variable into the id type of the domain class first and eventually access the instance through calling findById(…) on the repository instance registered for the domain type.`

Comment: can you show your TreeSource class?

Comment: Not `TreeSource`, it's named `Tresource` and, sorry, I can't - it's confidentional.

Answer (score 2):

Solution found!

In my code sample, I used

```
public interface UserRepository extends Repository<Tresource, Long> {
```

but `getOne(ID)` and `findOne(ID)` are in the `CrudRepository` class.

So, I fixed my code to this code and everything works well now:

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<Tresource, Long> {
```